# How to run Query in loops and counts the number of rows of each loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a query that collects data for me, at the end of it I'm filtering on two dates and I count the number of rows.

```
FROM TAB
WHERE
      (tab.transfer_date < '2019-03-11' AND  Real_Updated_date >= '2019-03-11') 
      ORDER BY transfer_date
```

Is there a possibility to increase both dates by '1' till '2019-03-20'
and count and print how many rows I had in each day?
Thanks!

Full Query:

```
WITH TAB AS (
SELECT 

      [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.updated_datetime
       ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.transfer_date
      ,cast(
       case
            when  [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.transfer_date = [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.updated_datetime then getdate()
            else [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.updated_datetime end as datetime
             ) as Real_Updated_date

  FROM [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_material_location]

  join [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_material_unit]
  on vw_public_material_location.material_name = vw_public_material_unit.unit_number

   JOIN [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_history] 
  ON [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].vw_public_material_location.material_id = [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.material_id
  where 

    DateDiff(d,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.transfer_date, getdate()) < 30
    AND
    [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].vw_public_material_location.quantity = 1

    and
     [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.location_id  in ('3492','3500','3981','3493','3504','3497','4140',
     '3498', '3496','3627','4378','3512','4376','4542','4379','3802','4517','4410','4182','4758','3499','4897','4239','4820',
     '4133','4377','4342','5042','5113','5358','5100','5550','5548','5549','5359',
     '5594','5601','5614','5696','5701')
     )

select tab.*
FROM TAB
where
      (tab.transfer_date < '2019-03-11' ANd  Real_Updated_date >= '2019-03-11') 
      order by transfer_date
```

Comment: try this `(tab.transfer_date < '2019-03-11  23:59:59.000' ANd  Real_Updated_date >= '2019-03-11 00:00:00.000' )  `

Comment: I think you miss understand me. I wonder how I can to it automatically and increase time filter '2019-03-11' by "1" to '2019-03-12' and so own (plus print the number of rows for each search)

Comment: for that you can use: DATEADD method to increase the date or time. [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). you can do Group by date to get the SUM value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @dateFilter datetime, @enddate datetime
DECLARE @mycounts AS TABLE (mydate datetime, mycount int)
DECLARE @mydata AS TABLE (updated_datetime datetime, transfer_date datetime, real_updated_date datetime)

INSERT INTO @mydata
SELECT 

  [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.updated_datetime
   ,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.transfer_date
  ,cast(
   case
        when  [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.transfer_date = [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.updated_datetime then getdate()
        else [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.updated_datetime end as datetime
         ) as Real_Updated_date

  FROM [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_material_location]

  join [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_material_unit]
  on vw_public_material_location.material_name = vw_public_material_unit.unit_number

   JOIN [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[material_history] 
  ON [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].vw_public_material_location.material_id = [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.material_id
  where 

    DateDiff(d,[vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.transfer_date, getdate()) < 30
    AND
    [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].vw_public_material_location.quantity = 1

    and
     [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].material_history.location_id  in ('3492','3500','3981','3493','3504','3497','4140',
     '3498', '3496','3627','4378','3512','4376','4542','4379','3802','4517','4410','4182','4758','3499','4897','4239','4820',
     '4133','4377','4342','5042','5113','5358','5100','5550','5548','5549','5359',
     '5594','5601','5614','5696','5701')
     )

    SET @dateFilter = '2019-03-11' --this is the first date used as filter
    SET @enddate='2019-03-20' --this is the last one

    WHILE @dateFilter <= @enddate
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @mycounts

        SELECT @dateFilter, count(*) as mycount FROM @mydata tab
        WHERE
            (tab.transfer_date < @dateFilter AND  Real_Updated_date >= @dateFilter) 

        SET @dateFilter = DATEADD(day,1,@dateFilter)
    END

SELECT * FROM @mycounts
```

By using DATEADD you are going to be able to filter different months/years as well.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is going to give error because it's not included in any GROUP BY statement. Since it's not useful in counting rows, it can be removed from the script.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to edit my Query but I probably miss something, there is a possibility that you show me how the above solution can be implemented in my Query I added it to the main issue.